# is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Created a function

```
CREATE FUNCTION Split_On_Upper_Case(@Temp VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @KeepValues AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @KeepValues='%[^ ][A-Z]%'
WHILE PATINDEX(@KeepValues COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,@Temp)>0
SET @Temp=STUFF(@Temp,PATINDEX(@KeepValues COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,@Temp)+1,0,' ')
RETURN @Temp
END
```

When iam trying to exexute this `SELECT Split_On_Upper_Case('SaiBharath')` It gives an error "'Split_On_Upper_Case' is not a recognized built-in function name.".Can someone please explain this

Comment: @Mansoor - Please?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Add [dbo] in prefix and then execute as same :

```
SELECT [dbo].[Split_On_Upper_Case] ('SaiBharath')
```

Comment: Good answers have not only code but also some explanation.

Comment: To be fair, Microsoft seem to provide very little explanation of this either. This answer has been enough to solve the frustration I've had for the past half hour trying to execute functions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer to this but I wonder if there is a way of avoiding using dbo. ? Please see my question here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52953159/user-scalar-valued-function-without-the-dbo-part

Comment: Even this is not solving the problem. I am getting "Function not found" error, even i have reconnected the server and restarted to refresh the memory. thanks

Answer (score 13):

To execute function in sql, prefix `dbo` should be used.

```
SELECT [dbo].[Split_On_Upper_Case] ('SaiBharath')
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to make sure, set the database you created your function on first by using the `use` clause and then prefix the call of your function with `dbo`.

```
USE <DatabaseName>

SELECT dbo.Split_On_Upper_Case('camelCase')
```

Also, a good practice is [prefixing each function or database object for that matter, with its schema name](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix).