# User Scalar-valued function without the [dbo]. part

Tags: sql-server

I work on a reporting tool (based upon JasperReports) that uses multiple types of database (Postgresql, Sql Server, Oracle). All platforms share a common Jasper domain, and some of these domains require common scripted sql select queries (eg select blah from table xxx ..)

In one particular script I need to reference a user-function that is created on all platforms.

The issue is, for the script, I can reference this function as

```
select my_func(col1, col2) from some_table
```

on both PostgreSQL & Oracle installations. But the same query cannot be run as is on SQL Server as a get '***my_func is not a recognized built-in function name.***' error message.
To make it work I have to qualify the function with `dbo.`, ie

```
select dbo.my_func(col1, col2) from some_table
```

But of course this won't work on Oracle & Postgresql.

So my question is there anyway of creating this function on SQL Server to be able to call it without having to qualify it with the `dbo.` part.

Comment: `... course this won't work on Oracle & Sql Server` <= I think you meant `Oracle & PostgreSQL`?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Corrected the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it mentioned above by Michael G, you should specify `dbo` on SQL Server. So the question is the multi-DBMS support. There are several solution at programming level like preprocessing the SQL code.

You may also encapsulate the function in the view and use it on Oracle and PostgreSQL

SQL Server

```
CREATE VIEW my_func_view AS SELECT dbo.my_func(col1, col2) AS col12 FROM some_table
```

Oracle

```
CREATE VIEW my_func_view AS SELECT my_func(col1, col2) AS col12 FROM some_table
```

In the code

```
SELECT * FROM my_func_view
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's possible for SQL Server.

> Scalar-valued functions can be invoked where scalar expressions are
>   used. This includes computed columns and CHECK constraint definitions.
>   Scalar-valued functions can also be executed by using the EXECUTE
>   statement. **Scalar-valued functions must be invoked by using at least
>   the two-part name of the function.** For more information about
>   multipart names, see Transact-SQL Syntax Conventions (Transact-SQL).
>   Table-valued functions can be invoked where table expressions are
>   allowed in the FROM clause of SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE
>   statements. For more information, see Execute User-defined Functions.

Emphasis added

**See:**

- [MSDN - Creation Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#general-remarks)
- [MSDN - Multi-Part Naming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/transact-sql-syntax-conventions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#multipart-names)

You may be able to omit the schema, and reference the database name instead:

```
[database]..[object]
```

Comment: This is still true with [synonyms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as well